# getting an error while publish the on cloudflare workers?

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I have created a folder called workers and inside that, I have used these commands to setup
firstly i used npm init and
then i used npm i @cloudflare/wrangler
then it will created package.json and node_module folder and packagelock.json
and then i used this command to generate a worker site npx wrangler generate --site practice

and then i moved to the practice folder and added the account id in the .toml file and when i am using wrangler publish or npx wrangler publish i am getting an error [image]

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you need to run `wrangler login` or `wrangler config` to set the credentials for your account.

Comment: Hi @Kenton Varda,

I have same issue, running wrangler config doesn't help (I can see the token is set in .wrangler/config/default.toml)

wragnler login just hangs with waiting for API token..


After runing wrangler config token is set sucesfully, but still says "You have not provided your Cloudflare credentials."

Comment: @Froxz When you used `wrangler login`, did you open the URL it asked you to go to and approve the token? If you did that, and `wrangler` still never received it, then you may have network connectivity issues blocking wrangler from accessing the internet -- or maybe wrangler itself has a bug, which you might want to report on its github repo.

Comment: Hi @Kenton Varda

I think is a bug - Reported here: https://github.com/cloudflare/wrangler/issues/1703#issuecomment-797299364

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `sudo` when doing a global install, you need to use `sudo` everytime you call wrangler.
ex: `sudo wrangler dev`
OR
`sudo wrangler publish`
etc

even `wrangler login` and `wrangler config` will not work without `sudo`